# Display performance with relativeLayout containing a lot of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I encounter performances issues while using a RelativeLayout (wrapped into a ScrollView) containing 153 TextView. Each of the TextView has a 9 patch background.

The main layout:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/forum_accueil_ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/forum_accueil_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The RelativeLayout is filled with TextViews programmatically (the item count and description comes from a WS). Each of the TextView has a 9patch background selector. TextView description below:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:textColor="@color/myblue"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_forum_accueil_item">
</TextView>
```

At the end, I have a RelativeLayout containing 153 TextView. The display and scroll is really slow. Even coming back on this activity takes some time.

I opened the Hierarchy viewer and the ScrollView takes the following time to display:

Measure: 28ms
Layout: 1.2ms
Draw: 18ms

Is there a way to speed up the display and the responsiveness? Is a single RelativeLayout containing as much Views is the best way to do it (I tried to flatten as much as possible the hierarchy with this technique)?
I tried removing the 9 patch background for test, it seems much more responsive. Why?

Comment: It's slow because you drawing 153 views! The great thing about adapter views it that they only draw what is <em>needed</em> at the time. You are drawing <b>all</b> of your views, the vast majority aren't being viewed at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an obscene amount of TextViews. At that point use a ListView. What does your RelativeLayout do for you (in this instance) that a ListView can't?

Comment: I need to allow the user to navigate threw all of those TextView with both touch and trackball and I was afraid that the ListView, with it's cells, will not allow me to make it work exactly the same.

Comment: That is the point of a list view. To list a large amount of similar items.

Comment: Yes, but can it act exactly as a Relative layout? Can it handle navigation as a RelativeLayout in a ScrollView? In touchMode, I think I can make it, with the tackball not sure...

Comment: What do you mean: 'can it handle navigation as a RelativeLayout in a ScrollView'? With a track ball, when you scroll down, it will select the next item in the list.

Comment: Let me ask a better question. How are you organising the these views in a RelativeLayout? Are you stepping through with a loop and just adding the next view to the RL or do you go through by hand and individually add each view in its own unique location? What are you doing to these views that merits a RL?

Comment: I am using a loop to iterate threw the data (received from a WS) describing the data to display. After your advice, I've tried to replace the RelativeLayout by a ListView. It works nearly like the RelativeLayout so I'm going to use it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very clear: why is the rendering/layout time so much more responsive after taking out the 9-patch backgrounds?  There's actually 2 good answers:

1. specifying a background attribute vs using a style that includes a background attribute is much slower.  Styles are cached with the GPU so it already knows about the background and uses it.  If you don't specify a style, a style (a default style) is used anyway, and it *does* include a background of some sort and this is applied first.  Then the view-specific attributes are applied i.e. your specified background is re-rendered.
2. 9-patch images *can* take **much** longer to render.  Couple this with the fact that you're asking for it to be rendered 153 times and the performance is going to be exponentially worse.  I'm looking at a case right now where I'm seeing 'regular' .png bitmaps rendered in 1.5 ms while a very simple 9-patch in the same layout is 30x slower at 45 ms.

Caveat emptor: 9-patch rendering is *often*, but not always, impacted by a GC cycle that accounts for 80% of the rendering time.  In some instances I see this GC cycle take place while rendering other bitmaps/raster images, but it *does* appear to happen more often during 9-patch rendering.